# Get all reserved ip address for router

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, ip

I have computer where the user can set the static IP address. 
The problem is if somehow another computer have the same IP address which is set like a static, but right now is not connected to the network.

After both computers is connected then will have problem and try both computers have same IP address on one network.

My question is: Is it possible to get all IP addresses which is used from router or is possible to used like static IP addresses in the future?

Sorry for my bad language.

I used  that command but is return only IP addresses which now is connected. I need all IP addresses which is already set to the router:

```
sudo arp-scan --interface=wlan0 --localnet| awk "{print $1}"|tail -n +3|head -n -2
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not specific to Ubuntu and router-related problems are off-topic here.

Comment: The administration pages of the router will tell you the addresses allocated for DHCP. Static addresses should be *outside* the DHCP pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although @Melebius has already mentioned that this is not specific to Ubuntu and you should ask the question at appropriate forum. However I will still try help you here (writing a script, which should be *acceptable* on this forum).

Most of the routers also support DHCP. So at first you can set your computer to acquire an IP address using DHCP. Then run the following script. This will give you all the IP addresses which are **currently** in use. However there is no way to know all the IP addresses allotted by the router, unless you are the system administrator / access to the router configuration (in such case the answer is trivial).

For the script, first create a conf file listing all possible IPs you suspect (one per line), say `pinglan.conf` and put it in `$HOME/bin`.

Then run the following script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#< Configurable script to ping my LAN

if [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "Usage: `basename $0`" && exit 1
fi


_TEMP_FILE=$HOME/tmp/pinglan.$$

trap 'rm -f $_TEMP_FILE; tput reset;  exit 1' 1 2 3 15

clear

_GREEN=`tput setf 2`
_RED=`tput setf 4`
_BLUE=`tput setf 1`

while read line
do
  _IP_ADDR=`echo $line | awk -F : '{ print $1 }'`
  _HOST_NAME=`echo $line | awk -F : '{ print $2 }'`
  ping -w 1 $_IP_ADDR > $_TEMP_FILE 2>&1
  grep "bytes from" $_TEMP_FILE > /dev/null 2>&1
  if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then # host is up
    echo "${_GREEN}$_HOST_NAME ($_IP_ADDR) is UP"
  else
    echo "${_RED}$_HOST_NAME ($_IP_ADDR) is DOWN"
  fi
    done < $HOME/bin/pinglan.conf

echo -e "\n\n${_BLUE}Press enter to continue..."
read dummy
# tput reset

rm -f $_TEMP_FILE
exit 0
```

## Note:

This code is not my original, but have been with me for years and I have modified to my needs! Dont have the original source. Thanks to the o

Hope this helps!

-- Mike